# Does ggplot2 library work in R version 4.0.5?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem loading a ggplot2 library in R. My R version is 4.0.5 and it is updated.
When I want to add the ggplot2 library I get this error:

> library(ggplot2)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’:
object ‘data_frame’ is not exported by 'namespace:vctrs'

Comment: Please reinstall ggplot2

Comment: I already did it but I get the same error

Comment: I am also getting same error even after re-installing "ggplot2" multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can try that:

```
    remove.packages(c("ggplot2"))
    install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
    install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

If it's not working, you may try to uninstall and remove all old versions of R and install the latest one again. I hope I could help.

Comment: This did not help.